# how efficient ionic works without angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I plan to develop mobile app in ionic with meteor. Will ionic works **without angularjs**? and How **efficient** ionic without angular?

Comment: There is a [meteor-ionic package](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic) which, while still being in development, has tried to implement a lot of the what ionic does. 

So yes, it definitely works but there are still some things that haven't been "ported" over to meteor.

Comment: @RamsayLanier Thanks, Its still in development. will you recommend this for production?

Comment: I've used it in production. I'm just saying that not all of the Ionic components are working yet. The github has a pretty good roadmap.

Answer (score 1):

I found these on Github, Maybe useful with what your trying to achive!
I hope this helps, Good luck.

https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic
https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-ionic